# Try to make a view but have a problem ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, i'm trying to make a view in sql

```
    CREATE VIEW VIEW_PROJECT 
AS SELECT Pname, Dname, COUNT(W.Essn) as Numb_Employees, SUM(W.Hours) as Total_Hours 
FROM PROJECT P, DEPARTMENT D, WORKS_ON W 
WHERE P.Dnum=D.Dnumber AND P.Pnumber=W.Pno 
GROUP BY Pno;
```

Then an error occured "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Could you tell me how to fix the query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: A couple of things with your query: 1) All non-aggregated columns should appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. 2) Please, please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92; this syntax is from SQL-89, the year of the lambada. Do you like lambada?

Comment: The "hands on"-way is to try the select statement alone (using "select count(1) ..." if the table is large) until you get your desired result. In my experience, this error results either from neglecting to put some field to the "GROUP BY", or from a query that can't be done that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate by the unaggregated columns n the `select`.  And use `JOIN`!

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_PROJECT AS
    SELECT p.Pname, d.Dname, COUNT(W.Essn) as Numb_Employees, SUM(W.Hours) as Total_Hours 
    FROM PROJECT P JOIN
         DEPARTMENT D
         ON P.Dnum = D.Dnumber JOIN
         WORKS_ON W 
         ON P.Pnumber = W.Pno 
GROUP BY Pname, Dname;
```

Comment: Just for curiosity: why use "JOIN!"? Aggregating tables, or aliases of, and combining them with conditions always worked fine for my. Really interested why you advocate JOIN.

Comment: Commas are archaic syntax that was superseded in the 1990s by the adoption of standard `JOIN` syntax.  `JOIN` is much more powerful, because is enables outer joins.  `JOIN` is much less prone to error because it mandates an `ON` clause for the conditions.  `JOIN` is considered more readable by most people, as well.

Comment: Please fix the invalid syntax in `JOIN table_name WHERE` (line 7) - should be `ON P.Pnumber=W.Pno`